# How to get complete user claims details using X-JWT-Assertion header in wso2 APIM 4.1?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

we are moving WSO2 API from 3.1 to 4.1.
In 3.1 we are getting user profile all claims in X-JWT-Assertion header
But 4.1 we are not getting all claims. we are seeing only default claims.
can you help us how to get all claims.?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow these steps.

1. Create an application in the devportal.
2. When you generate consumer key and secret in the devportal for this application, it creates the service provider underneath. This service provider will be available when you logged into the carbon console.
3. Click on the service provider and configure the claims under claim configuration. You can provide the required claims here as shown in the screenshot.

[image]

4. Update the user profile as in https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/identity-lifecycles/update-profile/
5. Use the openid scope when generating the access token.

> curl -k -X POST https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token -d
> "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin&scope=openid" -H
> "Authorization: Basic Base64Encoded(ck:cs)"

6. When the gateway generates the backend jwt, it adds the claims from the access token.